# How to run multiple node.js servers

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I have two Express servers running on different ports. The first server (web server) provides a website and the second server (data server) emits data every 100 ms using socket.io.
When I open the website in the browser the data appears as expected. But when I then open the website in a second browser, all the emitted data in the first browser slows remarkably down until the second browser is done loading the site.

I should probably mention that the application is running on a Raspberry Pi. The website loading time is not so critical, but the data emission is.

Is there some way to run the node.js servers so they won't be affected by the load on each other?

Right now the web server is in the main app.js file that is run by node and the data server is a module required by the web server. Something like this:

app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var data = require('data-server.js');

var app = express();

// Web server setup and handling (mostly Express defaults)

app.listen(3000);

module.exports = app;
```

data-server.js:

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app).listen(3001)
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

// Socket.io code that emits data every 100 ms

module.exports = io;
```

**Update**

Turns out it was my database query that was holding on to node so it couldn't emit because the emission function was waiting for the database to be free.

Comment: Why not run `socket.io` [over your Express connection](http://socket.io/docs/#using-with-express-3/4)? Also, are you actually starting a _new_ browser, or are you just opening a new tab/window?

Comment: I do use socket.io over an Express connection - unless I misunderstood something, I'm new to all this. I started a new browser, the first browser was Chrome and the next was Safari.

Comment: You're starting two servers, one on 3000 and one on 3001. That's superfluous, you can run the `socket.io` server on top of the Express server that's running on 3000. The slowdown may not be caused by that, but like Tristan points out in his answer, at least is saves resources.

Comment: Okay, now I got it. Thank you. So is there any benefits of running on different ports at all? I haven't been able to find any readings on this.

Comment: There _may_ be use-cases to run on separate ports, but I can't think of any offhand :-) (perhaps different loadbalancer/proxy/caching paths)

Answer (score 4):

You should use the same port and the same node process for both your regular HTTP traffic and your websocket traffic. It would minimise the performance impact on your raspberry pi. Example :

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile('index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Comment: If I use same port and same node process, can I then transmit on different socket.io connections simultaneously? That is what I'm trying to achieve, if that is even possible.

Comment: @KMK did you ever come to a final solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

[image: multiple-node-servers]Method 1: `Infinite-Servers.js` : Start 1000 servers in one run

```
const express = require('express')
var app=new Array(10)

for (let i = 3000; i <= 4000; i++) {
    app[i]=express()
    app[i].get('/',(req,res)=>res.send({'port': i}))
    app[i].listen( i,()=>console.log('port', i,"started"))    
}
```

Method 2: `MultiServers.js` : Start 2 servers:

```
const express = require('express')
server=express()
server2=express()

server.get('/',(req,res)=>res.send({"server":"3001","name":"aakash4dev","data":"some data 1"}))

server2.get('/',(req,res)=>res.send({"server":"3002","name":"aakash4dev","data":"some data 2"}))
server2.get('/somethig',(req,res)=>res.send({"server":"3002","name":"aakash4dev","data":"some data 2"}))

server.listen(3001)
server2.listen(3002)
```

Method 3: `SepetareInfiniteServers.js`

If you want to keep all files separately, e.g. port1.js port2.js port3.js .... port1000.js, all in different files and start all servers on a single run, then use `module.exports` (official docs: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#moduleexports ) along with the first  `InfiniteServers.js` codes above. codes will look like this:

```
var portsData=new Array(3)

 const express = require('express')
 const cors=require('cors')
 var app=new Array(3)
 
 for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
     portsData[i]=require('./port'+i)
     app[i]=express()
     app[i].use(cors())
 
     app[i].get('/',(req,res)=>{
         let req_requestedData={"name":"aakash4dev"}
         res.send(require('./port1.js').fun1({req_requestedData,"our-Response":"Im server"}))
     })
     
     app[i].listen( i,()=>console.log('port', i,"started"))    
 }
```

note: import `cors` module and use `app[i].use(cors())` in array or `app.use(cors())` in normal servers to remove error `cors policy no 'access-control-allow-origin'`