# What is the proper way to start multiple local node.js servers?

Tags: javascript, node.js, user-experience

I'm creating an example project for an open source framework. For my demo to run, some of it's dependencies must be running local servers on other ports.

I'd rather just provide them a single command to run instead of telling them to open multiple terminals and run multiple commands in each.

What is the best/most proper/most elegant way to go about this?

Comment: If you need a semblance of control over the underlying services, you may consider running a main process and using `child_process.fork` to spawn the remaining servers and processes. I like this approach since it allows me to monitor and manage the processes, as well as consolidating console output, and IPC.

Comment: 3 good ways to start 1000+ servers on single click: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71831233/17576982

Answer (score 5):

This is how I accomplish this for two web servers. You should be able to play with more `&`'s and `fg`'s to get more servers.

**package.json**:

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node node_modules/something/server.js & node server.js && fg
    }
}
```

So the user only has to run `npm install` and then `npm start` to run two servers in one terminal and `ctrl-c` kills both.

**Breakdown:**
`node node_modules/something/server.js &` run this server in the background
`node server.js &&` run my server in the foreground
`fg` move the most recently backgrounded shell into the foreground

Comment: Also worth noting that you'll want to make sure each is configured to run on a different port.  In most cases, Node servers take a PORT environment variable to do that.

Comment: This causes a redirect for my second server. How do you create two independent shells and execute a script in either?

Answer (score 3):

If you use the npm package call 'concurrently' set up your package.json file as below

you can use the following 3 commands
run only server

> npm run server

run only client

> npm run client

run both

> npm run dev

```
  "scripts": {
    "server": "nodemon server.js --ignore client",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""
  },
```

Answer (score 3):

For those who want this case:

If you want to run a single script that will open multiple terminals and run different nodejs servers on each you can do something like *(this is for windows.. for other os you can change command)*:

*You can write a single nodejs file that will start all your other servers in different terminal windows*

**startAllServers.js:**

```
const child_process = require('child_process');

// commands list
const commands = [
    {
        name: 'Ap1-1',
        command: 'cd ./api1 && start nodemon api1.js'
    },
    {
        name: 'Ap1-2',
        command: 'cd ./api2 && start nodemon api2.js'
    }
];

// run command
function runCommand(command, name, callback) {
    child_process.exec(command, function (error, stdout, stderr) {
        if (stderr) {
            callback(stderr, null);
        } else {
            callback(null, `Successfully executed ${name} ...`);
        }
    });
}

// main calling function
function main() {
    commands.forEach(element => {
        runCommand(element.command, element.name, (err, res) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
            } else {
                console.log(res);
            }
        });
    });
}

// call main
main();
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users also with similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

Use [concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently) npm package.

`concurrently "node server.js" "node client.js"`

This allows you to write multiple commands with clean output in one go. And they don't just have to be node servers. You can combine any bash commands.

Comment: Combined with package.json, you could place all of that in a single script like you wanted it to be.

Comment: You can start multiple servers in one terminal window? You need a separate terminal window for each server. Concurrently will work great for commands that can be run in the same shell - but once you fire up a server - you're in a different context and the next server isn't going to launch...